# Define terminal window title in Linux's *.desktop files

Tags: linux, terminal

On my Linux machine, I have some programs that I usually run from *.desktop file. In these files, I set the 'Terminal' value to 'true' as I would like to be able to monitor the output of the program.

The problem I am having with this is that the terminal window that opens has the title 'Terminal' only without the program's name or anything, which makes it more difficult to figure out which terminal window belongs to which program if I am running a couple of them at the same time.

So the question is: Is there a way to define the title of the terminal window that opens?

There is a workaround of course, by just running the programs directly from terminal, but the *.desktop files are more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Most terminals have an option to set the title, eg:-

```
xterm -T "Application name" -e "app and parameters"

mate-terminal -t "Application name" -e "app and parameters"
```

For some reason `gnome-terminal` doesn't have a title option, so you need to add to `.bashrc` the line:

```
[ "$TERM_TITLE" ] && xtitle "$TERM_TITLE"
```

Then use this string in the launcher:

```
env TERM_TITLE="app name" gnome-terminal -e "bash -ic 'app and parameters'"
```

Note that you need the `-i` option to make sure that `bash` reads `.bashrc`.

Another alternative is to use `bash --rcfile=apprc ...` with a separate `apprc` with its own `xtitle` command for each application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. There is just one thing that I forgot to mention.. I am using gnome-terminal with fish shell instead of bash.. So, how can I adapt this solution to fish?

Comment: I don't know `fish`, but there seems to be a `fish_title` function, which you can use to set the title automatically to the last foreground command executed, as [here](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#other). If you set this into one of your initialisation files, this should do the job, though as I read the documentation it should already be doing this (from fish 2.2). Maybe you just need to add `-i` to the `fish` run options to make it read the initialisation files. Otherwise, use a technique similar to what I described above for `gnome-terminal`, but in `fish` syntax.

Comment: I know about `fish_title` and `fish` is setting it by default to show the name of the process when I run programs from terminal, but it isn't doing it when the program is run from the *.desktop file

Comment: Did you try adding `-i` to the run options, as I did with `bash`?

Comment: Yes I did... but it didn't work at all

Comment: Without installing and learning `fish`, I don't think I can help further. Is there a reason why you can't use `bash` as the shell instead? This is the only solution I can suggest now.

Comment: Nothing specific.. I just prefer `fish` as it is easier to customize, and the auto-completion is much better... I think I will just launch the programs I want from terminal.. this might even be better, as the terminal window won't close if one of these programs crashed.. might be a bit slower, but it might be more useful.. Thank you very much for your help.